# How do I get DateTime in flutter with microseconds?

Tags: flutter

I am storing several rows in Postgres (Supabase) and want to use a timestampz field both as the date of creation as well as to "group" these rows.

When I use the now() of postgres the timestampz has microseconds, whereas the DateTime.now() of flutter has only milliseconds.

See image that shows the difference
[image: Image from Supabase Table]

What I am doing now is to write the first record (using the column default set to now()), read it to get the timestamp and then set this for the other rows.

Is there a way to generate DateTime.now() with microseconds in flutter?

Comment: This difference might be due to the `dateFormat` being used by respective platform. Consider using an appropriate `DateFormat` for this issue.

Comment: `DateTime.now()` normally reports microseconds.  Are you using Flutter *for the web*?  Web browsers limit timing resolution to milliseconds in an attempt to mitigate against timing-based attacks.

Comment: Yes, I am using flutter for the web!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `millisecondsSinceEpoch` to get milliseconds from datetime.

```
final now = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
print(now);
```

This will return you milliseconds since the "Unix epoch" 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/millisecondsSinceEpoch.html